# Matching two titles by words and calculate %

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to automate an Excel file which has title in both A and B columns and I have to search each word from A within B and calculate the % by using the "no of words matched/total no of words (in column A)" formula.

I'm using the below code, however its not giving me the accurate % for which the title has repeated words (Duplicate words).

```js
Sub percentage()
Dim a() As String, b() As String
Dim aRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer
Set aRng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A5").End(xlDown))
For Each cel In aRng

   a = Split(Trim(cel), " ")
   b = Split(Trim(cel.Offset(, 1)), " ")
   d = 0
   c = UBound(a) + 1 
If cel.Value <> "" Then
  If InStr(cel, cel.Offset(, 1)) Then
      d = UBound(b) + 1
Else
     For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
         For t = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
             If UCase(a(i)) = UCase(b(t)) Then
                 d = d + 1
             End If
       Next
    Next
 End If
End If
cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (d / c) 
Next
End Sub
```

If Title 1 : Really Nice pack with Nice print and Title 2 : Nice Print Nice pack then result should be 3/6 i.e. 67%.

But I'm getting a result as 100%.

Can anyone help me out please.

Titles are

Great job dud

Really Nice pack with Nice print

To give success and success process

Don’t eat too much. If you eat too much you will get sick

**I have tried =noDuplicate(celladdress)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should delete duplicate word in column B.

My function delete word and return array of word that not duplicate.

```
Function noDuplicate(ByVal str As String) As String()
Dim splitStr() As String
Dim result() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim addFlag As Boolean

splitStr = Split(UCase(str), " ")
ReDim result(UBound(splitStr))

'
result(0) = splitStr(0)
k = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(splitStr)
    addFlag = True
    For j = 0 To k
        If splitStr(i) = result(j) Then
            addFlag = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If addFlag Then
        result(k + 1) = splitStr(i)
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve result(k)
noDuplicate = result
End Function
```

Then calculate the percentage of number of match word and number of word in column A.

```
Function percentMatch(ByVal colA As String, ByVal colB As String) As Double
Dim splitColA() As String
Dim splitColB() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim matchCount As Integer

splitColA = Split(UCase(colA), " ")
splitColB = noDuplicate(colB)

matchCount = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(splitColA)
    For j = 0 To UBound(splitColB)
        If splitColA(i) = splitColB(j) Then
            matchCount = matchCount + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

percentMatch = matchCount / (UBound(splitColA) + 1)
End Function
```

After add these two function, you can write your new code to below

```
Sub percentage()
Dim aRng As Range, cel As Range

Set aRng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A5").End(xlDown))
For Each cel In aRng
    cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = percentMatch(cel.Value, cel.Offset(0, 1).Value) 
Next
End Sub
```

Note, I not protect for empty string in the function.

Comment: Thanks for the code @Adisak. However your first function **noDuplicate** is not working, it returns only the first word of the title in a cell. I'm trying to find the root cause :)

Comment: Could you give me the title you tried and how you call the function

Comment: I have updated the tiles in the bottom of my question please take a look.

Comment: You shoud use =percentMatch(A1,B1) not =noDuplicate(celladdress), The function =noDuplicate(celladdress) is used in percentMatch function.

Comment: Hi Adisak, apology for delay in response. Yep that's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you F8 through the code, you can see the problem.

The first Nice in column A loops through column B and counts 2 occurences.
Pack in column A loops through column B and counts 1 occurence.
The second Nice in column A loops through column B and counts 2 occurences.
Print in column A loops through column B and counts 1 occurence.

So you get a count of 6 against the 6 words in column A; 100%

If you add a random word to column A, you'll get 6 out of 7.

Comment: Yeah I got it could you please tell me in breif how I can resolve this.